# Using unit testing framework for C Check

Tags: c, check-framework

I am trying to use unit testing framework for C called [Check](http://check.sourceforge.net).

I installed the package as instructed on the file INSTALL in the package:

1. **./configure**
2. **make**
3. **make check** -> run self-tests that come with the package (pass successfully).
4. **make install**

After doing that I failed to run my own test so finally I decided to use the package example in `/usr/local/share/doc/check/example`.

Did the following commands:

```
$ autoreconf --install
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check
```

And still the same problem :

```
/usr/local/share/doc/check/example/tests/.libs/lt-check_money: error while loading shared libraries: libcheck.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
FAIL: check_money
```

Tried to add the directory to `LDFLAGS` in the make file but that did not help, also tried to do what Rick Hightower did [here](http://www.jroller.com/RickHigh/entry/unit_testing_in_c)
(...deleting the *.so files (and their **links**)) by I don't know how to remove the links

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try running `ldconfig` (ie. `sudo ldconfig`) to rebuild the runtime linker cache.

Answer (score 2):

On my system at least (Debian), libcheck isn't packaged as a shared library, you have to link it statically, e.g.

```
gcc -o test_program test1.o test2.o /usr/lib/libcheck.a
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can place the line `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/` (adjust path to location of your libcheck installation - if you installed it for a single user it may be in `/home/$user/usr/lib/`, for example) in your `.bashrc`. After `source ~/.bashrc`ing it, it should work. This way it should work for your other projects too.

Answer (score 0):

This project uses check https://github.com/batousik/Practical-C2

1. For some reason a folder m4 is required
2. .travis.yml has instructions for dependences
3. after it is run script -
4. configure.ac, makefile.am, src/makefile.am, tests/makefile.am are files to look at